# What is the meaning of the number left side of the title in delete tab?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools

I always wondering the meaning of this number on [delete tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete). What is this for?

[image]

The number of the right side shows the votes count for delete this question/answer but I couldn't figure out what is that number for. It doesn't have a tool tip neither. Looks like it is `1` as a default.

Comment: Number of votes???

Comment: @Tijesunimi No it is not. It shows also same number (`1`) who has 1 or 2 delete votes questions.

Comment: I meant the count of (upvotes - downvotes). I don't have 10k rep so I can't confirm

Comment: @Tijesunimi Nope, it doesn't neither. There are questions who has `-7` votes and still shows `1` as this number.

Comment: Well, it's not always 1. If you click "2d" or "7d" for example to see delete votes from last 2/7 days you'll see higher numbers there, though I still can't see any pattern.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hmm, you have a point. Still can't see any pattern neither `:)`

Comment: My best guess: this is the number of flags pending on those posts. Just a guess though. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's the number of votes of the relevant type that have been cast **in the time period selected**.

So on https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last7days, it's the number of votes cast **in the last 7 days**, and so on.

*edit*

I don't know if this has just happened, but **the expand-y section titles now have tooltips**, eg '> Delete votes' now has a tooltip of "Questions with delete votes in the date-range, by count of delete votes".

Comment: What is the meaning of _relevant type_ here? All votes are not type of delete? For example, in [7d part](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last7days), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981/how-many-lines-of-code-is-too-many) seems as `3 How many lines of code is too many? [closed] (4)`. So that means this question got `3` delete vote on **last 7 days**?

Comment: @SonerGönül that's how I read it, yes. by 'relevant' type: in Delete votes section, it counts delete votes; in Undelete votes, it counts undelete votes; etc

Comment: Yeah, I'm 99% sure a dev added the tooltips after seeing this question here on Meta.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What tooltip? I still don't see any.

Comment: @SonerGönül [see this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ljF.png) but I was wrong, it exists for long time as confirmed [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1761429#1761429).  :)